# I am not able to run DOTA2 on steam (Ubuntu 16.04LTS)

Tags: steam

Every time I try to start the game I get an error saying only one instance of the game should be running at one time. How do I fix this?( I am a newcomer to ubuntu)

Edit:I finally managed to run the game using playonlinux. The graphics are smooth.Can't say the same about the mouse movement. It is pretty decent but a bit jerky at times.Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: What if you reboot and try again?

Comment: Well that fixes the error I stated,but the game doesn't run at all. The steam tab says it's running but the game doesn't launch at all. Would there be any dependency issues?

Comment: Same issue here - I'm with ATI Radeon R9 290, seems to be related to the missing proprietary driver, and for now we have to go back to previous LTS...